# How to remove this bathroom faucet?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, cartridge

does anyone out there know the manufacturer of this faucet or how to remove the cartridge? I can remove the handle but can't seem to unscrew the base. Thanks in advance.

[image: faucet]

[image: under sink]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is removable at this split [image]
Try to insert a flatbar or a slotted screwdriver and pry it up.

Answer (score 1):

If prying that top part up does not work, then it may be threaded - try using a pipe wrench (with some thin card to protect the finish) on that top part and unscrew it.